# Creating a function inside a custom WordPress Plugin

Tags: errors

I have created a plugin `plugin_sql.php` inside WordPress plugins directory.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: plugin_sql
Plugin URI: http://www.something.com
Description: Database Management Plugin
Author: Muhammad Ali Rashed
Version:1.0
Author URI: http:www.something.com
*/

add_action('admin_menu', 'plugin_sql_admin_actions');

function plugin_sql_admin_actions()
{
    add_options_page('plugin_sql' , 'plugin_sql' , 'manage_options' , __FILE__ , 'plugin_sql_admin');
}

function f(id) {
    document.getelementbyid(id);
}

function submitform() {
    f("mybutton").disabled = 'true';
}   

function plugin_sql_admin()
{
    <form id="my_form" onSubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
        <p> <input id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form"><span id="status"></span> </p>
    </form>
}
?>
```

Running this on Wordpress gives error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\exchangerwp\wp-content\plugins\plugin_sql\plugin_sql.php on line 23

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please correct your code. Nobody is a code sweeper here.

Comment: I have edited my question......A HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED

Comment: @MuhammadAliRashed from your CODE it looks like you have a problem understanding how PHP backend CODE works along with JavaScript and HTML frontend. [Scott's answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/260662/110572) may help, but I suggest you take a basic course on overall web development with PHP. I'm suggesting this based on your CODE only, so please don't take this personally. Also, for WordPress plugin development, please study this [Official WordPress Plugin Development Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting error is because you are mixing PHP CODE with JavaScript and HTML.

You cannot just write JavaScript CODE and HTML CODE within PHP. These functions will not work in PHP:

```
function f(id) {
    document.getelementbyid(id);
}

function submitform() {
    f("mybutton").disabled = 'true';
}
```

For JavaScript you need you use [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function to add JavaScript CODE in the frontend.

For HTML, you need to get out of PHP mode properly. Like this:

```
function plugin_sql_admin()
{
    ?>
    <form id="my_form" onSubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
        <p> <input id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form"><span id="status"></span> </p>
    </form>
    <?php
}
```